# How can I prevent flyway callbacks from running when the target database is newer than the last migration present in the classpath?

Tags: flyway

I would like to stop the flyway callbacks (afterMigrate method in particular) from running if the database is newer than the last available migration file in the classpath. Flyway logs a warning in this scenario from the class DbMigrate:

> Schema "public" has a version (11.2.5) that is newer than the latest
>   available migration (11.2.4) !

However I would like to take some custom action for this scenario (throw an exception).
I am using Flyway 5.0.7

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `flyway.ignoreFutureMigrations` is for. Set it to `false` and you should be all set. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#ignoreFutureMigrations

Comment: Thank you, I somehow missed that property.